# Is it possible to edit previous sprint name in jira green hopper?

Tags: jira, sprint

I made a mistake in naming the sprint in jira board now i got to know about it. so now i want to edit those sprint names to avoid ambiguity in future.
Is it possible to change?

That is not the present sprint which is going on. Those sprints are already finished now i want to edit them. How?

I can rename the current sprint by on hover to sprint name but how to change the previous sprint name

Answer (score 0):

The REST resource /sprint/{sprintId} looks like you can pass the existing sprintId parameter plus an updateSprintRequest object which has a name member variable.

Source code is in ./src/main/java/com/atlassian/greenhopper/web/rapid/sprint/CompleteSprintResource.java

Comment: just am using jira agile board i want to edit the name of the sprint

Comment: what should i do with this,/src/main/java/com/atlassian/greenhopper/web/rapid/sprint/CompleteSprintResource.java

Comment: @mdoar - Looks like this is not possible. "Sprints that are in a closed state cannot be updated." from the API documentation at https://docs.atlassian.com/greenhopper/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/sprint-updateSprint